# Similar software known as Audioease Speakerphone ?

Tags: cheap, software, effect, prices, sound-effects

Hi !

Similar software known as Audioease Speakerphone ?
Thinking of something cheaper.
Perhaps some alternative?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Alternative if you have the time and means:

**Worldizing.**

Answer (score 3):

McDsp Futzbox? Sale on at the moment $150. Ends tomorrow though so be quick!

Comment: Thanx, looks good! Never heard of this.

Answer (score 3):

Yep Futzbox is pretty good. Don't be afraid to try to emulate things yourself using EQ, distortion, and the Lo-Fi plugin that comes with Pro Tools.

I have to admit that Speakerphone is amazing though!

Comment: +1 I'm all oldschool like this.  Marrying these with some of the Futz IR presets in TLSpace do a great job.  I love playing with Air LoFi too, allows you to add some nice digital grit.